# get data from edittext instance view

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have created a custom multiple EditText fields using a custom layout. Now the problem is don't know how to get data from these EditText when user clicks. Here's the button.

```
    b.setId(MY_BUTTON);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast;
            Log.w(TAG, "View Id: " + v.getId());
            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cliquer",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25,400);
            toast.show();
            saveForm();

            final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
            View tempView;
            String assembledString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
                tempView = root.getChildAt(i);
                if (tempView instanceof EditText) {
                    assembledString += ((EditText) tempView)
                                    .getText().toString();
                    params.put(name,assembledString);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Data EditText : "+ assembledString);
                }
            /*
             * EditText et = (EditText)
             * ((ViewGroup
             * )v.getParent()).getChildAt
             * (i);
             */

        }
        savePost(action, params);
   }
   });
   ll.addView(b);
```

i solved my probleme 
this is solution

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Toast toast;
                                        Log.w(TAG, "View Id: " + v.getId());
                                        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cliquer",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25,400);
                                        toast.show();

                                         LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
                                         ViewGroup parent = container ;
                                         String[] array = new String[parent.getChildCount()];
                                         String[] arrayFields = new String[parent.getChildCount()];
                                         Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                         for (int i=0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++){
                                            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
                                            if (child instanceof EditText) 
                                            {
                                                EditText et = (EditText) child;
                                                array[i] = et.getText().toString();
                                                arrayFields[i] = et.getTag().toString();
                                                params.put( arrayFields[i],  array[i]);
                                                Log.d(TAG , "array : " +   array[i]);
                                                Log.d(TAG , "arrayFields: " +  arrayFields[i]);
                                                Log.d(TAG , "paramsString : " +   params);

                                            }
                                            else {  Log.d(TAG , "Mes autres Views : " + child );} 


                                        } 
                                         savePost(action, params);

                                    }
                                });
                                ll.addView(b);
```

Comment: Final variable is the cause for this issue

Comment: what do you mean by custom multiple EditText?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change following line.

`final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();`

**With**

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be solved only by **Tag**.
Use **editText.setTag(position)** to save position as I show or save Object Id whatever you like.

Example:

```
List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<>();

for(EditText et : editTextList){
    String tempString = et.getText().toString();
    params.put(name, tempString);
}
```

now you get what you want. :)

//This is how I solved

You can also use **List** to save your EditTexts.

First, add EditText to list after create.

Second, Use **editText.setTag(position)** to save position as I show or save Object Id whatever you like.

And on button Click, you can get data from EditText list. You can also know position or id from EditText's Tag.

Hope This will help you. This is the way I solved.

**Your sample code**

```
List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<>();

b.setId(MY_BUTTON);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast toast;
        Log.w(TAG, "View Id: " + v.getId());
        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cliquer",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25,400);
        toast.show();
        saveForm();

        final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();



            for(EditText et : editTextList){
                assembledString = et.getText().toString();
                params.put(name, assembledString);
            }

        savePost(action, params);
    }
});
ll.addView(b);
```

Comment: i have a probleme here   if (tempView instanceof EditText) {
                    assembledString += ((EditText) tempView)
                                    .getText().toString();
                    params.put(name,assembledString);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Data EditText : "+ assembledString);
                }

Comment: thanks bro , but dont working my instance view don't get value from edit text :

Comment: You don't need this code  LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
            View tempView;
            String assembledString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
                tempView = root.getChildAt(i);
                if (tempView instanceof EditText) {
                    assembledString += ((EditText) tempView)
                                    .getText().toString();
                    params.put(name,assembledString);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Data EditText : "+ assembledString);
                }

Comment: you just need to replace that code with my code. PS. you need to add your edittext to list.

Comment: yes but I dynamically create my edittext from json file that is I try to recover edittext in LinearLayout

Comment: yes me too, I dynamically create Edittext, Checkbox, RadioButton  :D. I update my answer, pls try to replace your code. Bye

Comment: i replacing my code with your code , but not working !!